# Android smoothScrollBy behaving badly

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `ListView` that I am calling `smoothScrollBy()` on.  95% of the time, the `smoothScrollTo()` behaves as intended.  However there are times that it does not end up in the intended spot!  I have verified that I am giving it the same value.  I notice that the smooth scrolling is not so smooth when the errors are made, however there are no other tasks that my application is performing that I would have control over.

I am not quite sure what is going on in the background but a likely culprit is garbage collection.

95% accuracy is not good enough in this situation.  I am going to have to implement some sort of a correction mechanism to make sure the `ListView` lands on the correct spot in these instances.

Is there a better way to use `smoothScrollBy()` other than simply calling `view.smoothScrollBy(distance, time);`?

Comment: Did you ever find a nice resolution for this? I'm now in exactly the same position, where I simply have to have 100% accuracy for `smoothScrollBy()`, but its actual operation is very inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, I ended up ditching ListView to get more control over the position using a ScrollView and just adding child Views to it.  Before I figured this out I was using a correction mechanism that would make sure it scrolled to the right spot, and the initiated another scroll if not.  Very imprecise and not acceptable for professional applications :(

Comment: Many thanks, Styler. Today I tried implementing a correction mechanism that basically applies multiple scrolls in an iterative fashion, with successive scrolls invoked (via a `Handler`) from an `OnScrollListener()`. I am surprised to say that the end result is extremely good. What I did was make the bulk of the scrolling occur very fast, but the final scroll over the final 500px is slow (400ms). This makes the entire scroll look very fluid and nice looking, rather like a single non-linear scroll. I'll have to try to find some time to put an example together and post it here.

Comment: That would be a great alternative answer.. good job :)

Comment: Use this function http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable) to post the action. Do not just run it on the main thread.

Comment: @Trevor Could you please post your correction mechanism as answer to this? Thanks!

Comment: @Trevor Can you post what you did finally.

Comment: I'll have to see if I can find the code, as this was going back a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try some of these:

Listview has its own scrolling mechanism. It scrolls when the content is added.

1. Assign listview height (android:layout_height) to match_parent or fill_parent.
2. If your assigning a adapter in a working thread. Do not perform any UI actions in the thread.

If these do not solve the issue. Please post the code where you assign the adapter to the list view if any. Or the relevant code.

Also the xml layout code.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

sometimes it will be because of the timing issue. When the views are added to your listview and the time you do

```
view.smoothScrollBy(distance, time);
```

the listview or the ui still need not get refreshed. So do this in the views post thread with a specific delay. Eg.

```
view.postDelayed(new Runnable{
    view.smoothScrollBy(distance, time);
},1000);
```

Comment: I dont think this is fluid enough.. this means you have to wait 1 second before you can initiate a scroll. that would be a show stopper with the application i was using this in

Comment: that 1 sec delay is just an example.. check how much time it needs for your views to get refreshed and then add that delay. It need not be a second. it can b even in milliseconds in your case.

Comment: This would be variable depending on the phone.. overall this answer is hackish and not going to work in a production environment